# Why my HaProxy is very slow when uploading files?

Tags: haproxy

I have several servers connected to HaProxy. Unfortunately, the file transfer speed is dramatically slow, a 400kb file transfers a few minutes, before I increased the timeout it took forever. Any advice?

Thanks

```
global
log /dev/log    local0
log /dev/log    local1 notice
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
option forwardfor
stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
stats timeout 300s
user haproxy
group haproxy
daemon
maxconn         5000
nbproc          5
cpu-map         1 0
cpu-map         2 1
tune.ssl.default-dh-param 4096
tune.ssl.cachesize 1000000
tune.ssl.lifetime 600
tune.ssl.maxrecord 1460
# Default SSL material locations
ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
crt-base /etc/ssl/private

# See: https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=haproxy&server-version=2.0.3&config=intermediate
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    ssl-default-bind-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2 no-tls-tickets
```

defaults
log global
mode    http
option  httplog
option  dontlognull
timeout connect 300s
timeout client  300s
timeout server  300s
errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend facme
bind 192.168.10.160:80
mode http
log global
option httplog
option http-keep-alive
acl acme var(txn.txnpath) -m beg -i /.well-known/acme-challenge/
http-request set-var(txn.txnpath) path
use_backend bacme if acme

backend bacme
mode http
log global
retries 3

frontend websites
bind 192.168.10.160:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/
mode http
option httplog
option http-server-close
#acl xxx var(txn.txnhost) -m str -i xxx
acl xxx var(txn.txnhost) -m beg -i xxx
acl xxx var(txn.txnhost) -m beg -i xxx
acl xxx var(txn.txnhost) -m beg -i xxx
acl xxx var(txn.txnhost) -m beg -i xxx
acl xxx var(txn.txnhost) -m beg -i xxx
acl xxx var(txn.txnhost) -m beg -i xxx
acl xxx var(txn.txnhost) -m beg -i xxx
http-request set-var(txn.txnhost) hdr(host)
#use_backend xxx if xxx
use_backend xxx if xxx
use_backend xxx if xxx
use_backend xxx if xxx
use_backend xxx if xxx
use_backend xxx if xxx
use_backend xxx if xxx
use_backend xxx if xxx

backend xxx
mode http
log global
server default 192.168.10.165:443 ssl verify none

backend xxx
mode http
log global
server default 192.168.10.166:443 ssl verify none

backend xxx
mode http
log global
server default 192.168.10.162:443 ssl verify none

backend xxx
mode http
log global
server default 192.168.10.167:443 ssl verify none

backend xxx
mode http
log global
server default 192.168.10.164:443 ssl verify none
`

Adding this lines:

`   maxconn         5000
nbproc          5
cpu-map         1 0
cpu-map         2 1
tune.ssl.default-dh-param 4096
tune.ssl.cachesize 1000000
tune.ssl.lifetime 600
tune.ssl.maxrecord 1460